# Is there any way to startUpdatingLocation when the location services of device are off?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an ios app related to tracking and tracking is starting on receiving a notification. In this, I want to handle a scenario that the location services of the device are off and tracking notification is received. then after some time user go to setting and turn on location services of device and doesn't launch my app. so is there any way to get location updates?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to call startUpdatingLocation() without location service enabled

Comment: Is there any way to handle this scenario??

Comment: Nope since you are using tracking. 
Here tracking i am considering location tracking.